# Load the data from oracle database to csv files using python

Tags: python, oracle

I have written python script to fetch the data from oracle database and load that data to csv file.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('SYSTEM/oracle123@localhost:1521/xe')
c = con.cursor()
sql = "select * from covid_data"
res = c.execute(sql)
t = pd.read_sql(sql,con)
t.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\covid.csv')
```

I want the script to be run everyday and load to csv file. But the challenge which I am facing here is I want to fetch the data on daily basis but the data in csv file should be available for only that particular day. The contents of previous day should not be seen the next day

Comment: do you mean that you want to select only the previous day data from oracle? you should be able to do that with your `select` query if the table enables it

Comment: no, i want to load the present day data to csv file. Previous day's data must not been seen in csv file.

Comment: my comment still applies. you need to write the SQL so that you will get the data you want

Comment: no, the  sql statement which i have written is correct. the thing here is when i select all the data from sql to csv file, it is adding present day's data along with the previous day's data. It should override the previous data

Comment: Yes, the select query is correct, if you want the whole data. If you want today's data, you need to alter it. It depends on how the data is stored in your table, which you didn't describe here, but it would be something like `select * from covid_data where <date_field> >= sysdate -1` or something like that. you don't need to select all the data if you only want today's data.

Comment: For future readers looking for more information about efficient loading of CSV files, see the cx_Oracle doc example: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#loading-csv-files-into-oracle-database

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for this.

In the below line, we have to add write mode, so that it will not append the data to csv file instead it overwrites.

```
t.to_csv(r'C:\Users\abc\covid.csv', mode='w')
```